# node.js GeoLib fails on polygon that straddles the anti-meridian

Tags: point-in-polygon, node-js

geolib.isPointInside does not appear to work correctly when the polygon longitudes straddle the anti-meridian.
I maintain a system with lots of polygons that do straddle the antimeridian (I'm in Australia :-) so it's important to me.

see the test code below that illustrates the problem when it's run in node:

```
var geolib = require('geolib');

// -------------
// Test 1 This succeeds
// -------------
var polygon = [
    {latitude: -46, longitude: 1},
    {latitude: -46, longitude: 2},
    {latitude: -47, longitude: 2},
    {latitude: -47, longitude: 1}
];
console.log('Test 1: Polygon:',polygon);
console.log('should be true', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:-46.5, longitude:1.5}, polygon))
console.log('should be false', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:-47.9, longitude:1.2}, polygon))
console.log('should be true', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:-46.8, longitude:1.1}, polygon))
console.log('------------');

// -------------
// Test 2 This succeeds
// -------------
var polygon = [
    {latitude: 10, longitude: -10},
    {latitude: 10, longitude: 10},
    {latitude: 20, longitude: 10},
    {latitude: 20, longitude: -10}
];
console.log('Test 2: Polygon:',polygon);
console.log('should be true', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:15, longitude:-5}, polygon))
console.log('should be false', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:15, longitude:-15}, polygon))
console.log('should be true', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:15, longitude:-5}, polygon))

// ----------
// Test 3 : AntiMeridian 1: This fails
// ----------
var polygon = [
    {latitude: 10, longitude: 175},
    {latitude: 10, longitude: -175},
    {latitude: 20, longitude: -175},
    {latitude: 20, longitude: 175}
];
console.log('Test 3: Antimeridian 1: Polygon:',polygon);
console.log('should be true', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:15, longitude:177}, polygon))
console.log('should be false', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:15, longitude:-170}, polygon))
console.log('should be true', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:15, longitude:-176}, polygon))
console.log('------------');

// ----------
// Test 4: Antimeridian 2: This fails
// ----------
var polygon = [
    {latitude: 10, longitude: -175},
    {latitude: 10, longitude: 175},
    {latitude: 20, longitude: 175},
    {latitude: 20, longitude: -175}
];
console.log('Test 4: Antimeridian 2: Polygon:',polygon);
console.log('should be true', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:15, longitude:177}, polygon))
console.log('should be false', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:15, longitude:-170}, polygon))
console.log('should be true', geolib.isPointInside({ latitude:15, longitude:-176}, polygon))
console.log('------------');
```